# How to use output events of Clarity Design's wizard?

Tags: angular, typescript

Given the code posted below, how can I correctly use `clrWizardOpenChange`,`clrWizardCurrentPageChanged` and `clrWizardOnFinish` ?

I am referring to the following page to learn how the API works:

[Clarity Design official docs for Wizards](https://clarity.design/documentation/wizards#examples)

But I cannot correctly use the aforementioned output event.

**code**:

```
<clr-wizard #ecoAssessWizard id="idWizard" 
    [(clrWizardOpen)]="showWizard" 
    [(clrWizardForceForwardNavigation)]="wizardForceForwardNav" 
    [(clrWizardDisableStepnav)]="wizardDisableStepnav"
    [clrWizardOpenChange]="onWizardOpenChange()"
    (clrWizardPreventDefaultCancel)="onWizardPreventDefaultCancel()"
    clrWizardSize="xl">
    <clr-wizard-title id="idWizardTitle"> {{ "SITE.FLOATING_BUTTON.ECO_ASSESS.LABEL" | translate}} </clr-wizard-title>

    <clr-wizard-button [type]="btnCancel">Cancel</clr-wizard-button>
    <clr-wizard-button [type]="btnPrevious">Back</clr-wizard-button>
    <clr-wizard-button [type]="btnNext">Next</clr-wizard-button>
    <clr-wizard-button [type]="btnFinish">Finish</clr-wizard-button>

    <clr-wizard-page #wizardPage1 id="idWizardPage1">
        <ng-template clrPageTitle>{{ "SITE.FLOATING_BUTTON.CONTENTS.ECO_ASSESS.STRING_WIZARD_PAGE_1_TITLE" | translate}}</ng-template>
    </clr-wizard-page>

</clr-wizard>
```

Comment: You should use Event bindings for output events such as clrWizardOpenChange. Try tho change the syntax to (clrWizardOpenChange)="onWizardOpenChange()"

Comment: @Chellappanவ can you please tell me how to use "clrWizardPageNextDisabled"? i tried to use like "[clrWizardPageNextDisabled]="wizardPageNextDisabled" but it does not disable the next button as stated in the official doc

Comment: As mentioned in the code example you can use [clrWizardPageNextDisabled]="wizardPageNextDisabled" on clr-wizard-page component : https://clarity.design/documentation/wizards#examples

Comment: @Chellappanவ thaks